# Can't install libpulse on Mac

Tags: macos, compilation, clang, homebrew, pulseaudio

I'm trying to compile some source code, and I'm getting the following error:

> ld: library not found for -l:libpulse-simple.0.dylib

I've figured out that I need to install the "libpulse-simple.0.dylib" file (and probably some other files too) into my /usr/lib directory, but I can't figure out how to do that. I've already run `brew install pulseaudio`, but is there another library I need to install?

Answer (score 0):

It's a compiling problem. The `libpulse-simple.0.dylib` has already been linked into `/usr/lib`. You just have to tell `ld` to find it. Fix the `PATH` of your compiling script. Or tell `ld` to search it explicitly by `-L/usr/lib`.